# network printer monitoring in .net

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, network-printers

I am developing printer monitoring system in .net. I need to track all network printer for monitoring and allow or restrict to print specific printer will do only print job with log data like which user done job for which customer.

Admin can allow and disallow specific printer from .Net application.

any idea, how to implement that code in .net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the network in a domain? Are the printers added to this domain?

Comment: no it's workstations on a Windows based Workgroup network

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you want to allow/disallow from an administrative panel all print jobs in a Windows work group based on some conditions. Which are these conditions?

Comment: allow/disallow printer which are accessed to user from .net window application. but all print job should be sent to the printer by my window application if accessible for logged user.

Comment: Is there any update on this? Were you able to solve this concern?

Answer (score 1):

i have done the same with .net 2 or 3 years ago
this helps me a lot

http://www.merrioncomputing.com/Programming/VBDotNet/WatchPrinter.htm